# HashSet prints blank values to the console

Tags: java, hash, set, nlp

why this nounPhrases is printing a blank [ ]  ? where i have done wrong ? I got a working  code from this site [(Woriking code exaple)](http://harmeetsingh13.blogspot.com/2013/05/search-noun-adjectives-verbs-from-text.html) and it works fine. But my code is not working. i cant print my nouns to the console. It prints a couple of [ ] in my console.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ParserAction;

import opennlp.tools.cmdline.parser.ParserTool;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parse;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parser;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserFactory;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserModel;

public class ParserTest {



    public static Set<String> nounPhrases = new HashSet<>();

        public String line="i need a java book";


    public void getNounPhrases(Parse p) {
        if (p.getType().equals("NN") || p.getType().equals("NNS") || p.getType().equals("NNP")
                || p.getType().equals("NNPS")) {
            nounPhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());
            // System.out.println(p.getCoveredText());
        }

        for (Parse child : p.getChildren()) {
            getNounPhrases(child);

        }
    }

    public void parserAction() throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
        ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);
        Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
        Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(line, parser, 1);
        for (Parse p : topParses) {
            // p.show();
            getNounPhrases(p);
        }
    }


    public void showNouns() {

        try {
            new ParserTest().parserAction();
            System.out.println("these are nouns"+nounPhrases);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("these are nouns"+nounPhrases);
    }


}
```

when i add main method to the class..it works fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      new ParserTest().parserAction();
      System.out.println("List of Noun Parse : "+nounPhrases);
```

Comment: Have you debugged through the code, or logged `p.getType()` in `getNounPhrases()`?

Comment: I called it inside my servlet class

Comment: That means it's an empty array and the line `nounPhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());` never executed. Check the value of `p` and make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: So have you tried creating a [mcve] outside your servlet environment, to make it easier to debug, for a start? What diagnostic steps have you performed?

Comment: I created an example project with two ParserTest classes and called the arrays in a separate class. that example is working fine.

Comment: when i add main method to the class..it works fine `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new ParserTest().parserAction();
    System.out.println("List of Noun Parse : "+nounPhrases);
    
   }`